# I can acces JSON data on one function but not in one other

Tags: javascript, json

My code has two function f1 and f2.
In f1 I set a jsonobject, which i can acccess.
But in f2 it's impossible (it will return "undefined").

The code is made to stock the adress of a street and is here (in summary)

```
locationForm.addEventListener('submit',f2);
var JsonStreet = {"Adresses":[]};


function f2(e){
while (streetNumber < streetEnd) {
console.log(JsonStreet.Adresses[0]); //here it is undefined
    f1(e);
    streetNumber ++;
  }
}


function f1(e){
e.preventDefault();
//creation of JsonAdress
JsonStreet.Adresses.unshift(JsonAdress);
//data adding to the Json depending on streetnumber
console.log(JsonStreet.Adresses[0]); //That's works well, the json seems good
}
```

Does someone know why there is a difference depending on the function?

EDIT :
here I had my code to be more precise :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <title>MyGeoCodeApp</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container"> //everything that will be display
    <h2 id="text-center"> Enter location :</h2>
    <form  id="location-form">
      <input type="text" id="location-input" class="form-control
      form-control-lg">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">submit</button>
</form>
  <h2 id="text-center"> Last street number :</h2>
<form  id="EndOfStreet-form">
  <input type="text" id="EndOfStreet-input" class="form-control
  form-control-lg">


</form>
  <div  class="card-block" id="formatted-address"></div>
  <div  class="card-block" id ="adress-components"></div>
  <div  class="card-block" id ="geo-components"></div>
  <div  class="card-block" id="json"></div>
  </div>

<script>
//call
//geocode();
//get location formattedAdd
var locationForm = document.getElementById('location-form');
var EndOfStreetForm = document.getElementById('EndOfStreet-form');
//listen for submit
locationForm.addEventListener('submit',streetAdresses);

var JsonStreet = {"Adresses":[]};
var streetNumber = 1;
var JsonAdress= {"Adress":" ","Latitude":" ", "Longitude":" "};


function streetAdresses(e)
{
  var EndOfStreet = document.getElementById('EndOfStreet-input').value;

 e.preventDefault();
  while (streetNumber-1<EndOfStreet) {

      var location = document.getElementById('location-input').value;
      location = streetNumber + location;
      //request to google to get the data
      axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
      params:{
        address:location,
        key:'PRIVATE_Key'
      }
    })
    .then(function(response){
    //Log full response
    //  console.log(response);
      //fornatted address
      var formattedAdd = (response.data.results[0].formatted_address);
      var formattedAddoUT = `
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">${formattedAdd}</li>
        </il>
      `;

    //adressComponents
  /*  var adressComponents = response.data.results[0].address_components;
    var adressComponentsOut = '<ul class="list-group">';
    for (var i = 0; i < adressComponents.length; i++) {
      adressComponentsOut +=`
    <li class="list-group-item">${adressComponents[i].types[0]} : ${adressComponents[i].long_name}</li>
      `;
    }
    adressComponentsOut += '</ul>'*/


    //geometricValues
    var lat  = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    var geoOutput=`
    <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">lattitude : ${lat}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">longitude : ${lng}</li>
    </ul>`;

    //set the json
    var JsonAdress = {"Adress":" ","Latitude":" ", "Longitude":" "};
    JsonAdress.Adress=formattedAdd;
    JsonAdress.Latitude=lat;
    JsonAdress.Longitude= lng;
    //var JsonObj = JSON.stringify(JsonAdress);

    JsonStreet.Adresses.unshift(JsonAdress);
    console.log(JsonStreet.Adresses[0]);  //that's go well


    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
    //}
    streetNumber ++;

  }
console.log(JsonStreet.Adresses[0]); //That's go "undefined"
console.log(JsonStreet); // That is well
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Finally, I attache a picture of what I get
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBtNP.png)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `JsonStreet.Adresses` is an empty array, so there is no value at position 0 (thus, it is *undefined*). Also see [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: I use unshift to add data in it in f1.And the consol.log (JsonStreet) will return a all json but not JsonStreet.Adresses[0] and that just in the console.log in f2.

Answer (score 0):

> The unshift() method adds new items to the beginning of an array, and
>   returns the new length.

So here in this line you are adding `JsonAdress` to `JsonStreet.Adresses` array

```
JsonStreet.Adresses.unshift(JsonAdress);
```

Therefore it is not empty here.

```
console.log(JsonStreet.Adresses[0]);
```

Also you are calling `f1()` inside `f2()` and accessing array before calling `f1()`. So your object is not modified till that time and it's empty array.

```
function f2(e){
    while (streetNumber < streetEnd) {
       f1(e);// call this function before console.log()
       console.log(JsonStreet.Adresses[0]); //now it is not undefined
       streetNumber ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not empty.   If I do a console.log(JsonStreet) in f2, i get in return the right thing, but i can't acces a specific data, just in f2

Comment: `JsonStreet.Adresses[0]` is `undefined` means array is empty inside `f2()` or the element you added is `undefined` . Since it is working fine in `f1()` it should be empty.

Comment: Hi @Nathan you need to call f1() before you access the value of that array. Updated my answer. Please let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help but it did not worked yet. I think i just need more time to understand javscript.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're printing your array and only populating it after.

You're executing `f2` inside `'submit'` `eventListener`, and you're executing `f1` inside of `f2` which means code for `f2` runs before `f1` code so your array is empty and you get undefined, then after `f1` runs it becomes defined and visible inside of your `console.log`

So to fix it you could just move your `console.log(JsonStreet.Adresses[0]);` down below `f1()`

Comment: So I should use a boucle inside f2 instead of f1 ?

Comment: You can also get rid of the problem by moving console.log after f1() and you don't need e.preventDefault in f1 add it to f2 instead